# Can I get the namespace of a type from within that type's constructor?

Tags: c#

Nancy modules all inherit from `NancyModule`. To register a module path, you supply the path as an argument to the base constructor.

```
public class BaseModule : NancyModule
{
    public BaseModule : base("/someFolder")
    {
```

Instead of some hardcoded folder, I would like to pass into the NancyModule constructor a folder name derived from the namespace of the most derived class. In a method, I could do this with `this.GetType().Namespace`, but since we're in a constructor, `this` is not available. In a constructor, is there some way of accessing the the type that is in the process of being created?

Comment: I assume you want the namespace of the derived type.

Comment: `typeof(TypeName).Namespace` ?

Comment: Are you able to modify the base class at all?

Comment: No not really. Not without a pull request to people much smarter than me.

Comment: `public BaseModule : base(typeof(BaseModule).Namespace) { ... }`

Comment: @Igor and Dimitriy, typeof won't help me because I want to inherit from my BaseModule, and it's the most derived type's info that I need. I believe Heizi has pointed me to the right answer. Well found.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think `this` isn't available in the constructor?

This works fine for me:

```
void Main()
{
    new Child();
}

public class Parent 
{ 
    public Parent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Namespace);
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
}
```

#### Update

Now that I look at it again, I realize you can't change the parent class. This should work, though:

```
public class Parent 
{ 
    public Parent(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(): base(typeof(Child).Namespace)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `this` inside `:base(....)` which is what the OP is attempting

Comment: Yup. But it's in the call to base() that I need the namespace. Not in the constructor body. Tis the red squiggle that makes me think I have a problem ;-)

Comment: @user1585345: Ah, I see. Is this something where only certain child classes would use this pattern, or could you put the code in the parent's constructor and avoid the need for the `base()` call entirely?

Comment: Only certain child classes. NancyModule is not my class.

Comment: @user1585345: Would it work to use `typeof()` (as in my second example)? Or are you hoping to have this child class have other child classes that it needs to figure out the type for?

Comment: By the way, this might be one of those cases where it helps to take a step back and see if favoring Composition over Inheritance could simplify things at all. For example, maybe you could have the factory or whatever that scans for and instantiates the modules pass a name and customization interface implementation as constructor arguments to a single `sealed` child class of NancyModule.

Comment: Totally agree, except I don't own NancyModule.